# Widget block editor: Unable to collect checkbox values inside widget update() method

Tags: widgets, block-editor

Users can select an item from the list (the items are actually listed inside a DIV container). Upon selection, the item is added below with a leading checkbox in checked mode. When saved, the items get saved.

[image]

This flow works fine when I activate the Classic Widget editor.

But with the Block Widget editor, the checkbox values are simply getting ignored. I am not getting them inside `$new_instance`.

Here is the code written inside the *update()* method of the Widget:

```
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
   $instance = $new_instance
   ....
   ....
   // Unfortunately, these don't come through $new_instance
   $instance['groups'] = is_array($_POST['groups']) ? array_values($_POST['groups']) : array();
}
```

I am never getting any value inside `$instance['groups']`.

I added an additional textbox (`<input type="hidden" name="instance-selected-groups" class="instance-selected-groups" value="' . $instance['instance-selected-groups'] . '" />`) where I am storing comma separated item values using JavaScript like this.

[image]

I tried to grab these values in the *update* method like this:

```
if( empty( $instance['groups'] ) ) {
    if( strlen( trim( $_POST['instance-selected-groups'] ) ) > 0 ) {
        $instance['groups'] = array_pop( explode( ',', $_POST['instance-selected-groups'] ) );
        var_dump( $instance['groups'] );
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either.

Comment: You shouldn't be checking `$_POST` in a widget's update method. You should be using `$new_instance` and your inputs need a proper dynamic name for that to work. You should review the documentation for developing widgets as it seems like your approach is just incorrect: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie for your quick reply. I am looking into the tutorial. However, the checkboxes get generated at client side, so I cannot get the instance for that. That is why I have to use $_POST approach for those. Moreover, this is an old widget and it runs perfectly fine with legacy widget editor, even today. But the problem starts onle on block editor. I can switch to classic widget editor, but rather I want to fix the issue and make it compatible for both editor modes.

Comment: Well your current approach won't work. I'd suggest looking at implementing this as a block.